# Expand Cells Containing 2D arrays Into Their Own Variables In Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

My data frame look like this

```
 TeamA   TeamB 
 [a,b]   [[b,c],[d,c],[d,f] .....upto 15  such arrays]
 [b,c]   [[v,c],[e,c],[g,f] .....upto 15  such arrays]
```

TeamB has 15 sets of records in each row.

I want it to look like

```
 TeamA   Team0 Team1  Team2 ...... 
 [a,b]   [b,c] [d,c]  [d,f]] ......
 [b,c]   [v,c] [e,c]  [g,f] .....
```

For 1D I can use

```
newcol = df['TeamB '].apply(pd.Series)
newcol = newcol.rename(columns = lambda x : 'Team_' + str(x))
pd.concat([df[:], newcol [:]], axis=1)
```

How can i do that with 2D arrays.

Here is my df.head(5).to_dict(). In this case i have taken only 2 arrays per row in TeamB

```
{'TeamA   ': {0: array([ 35.82, -95.67]),
  1: array([ 36.27, -95.91]),
  2: array([ 35.99 , -95.88]),
  3: array([ 36.18, -96.40]),
  4: array([ 35.99 , -95.90])},
 'TeamB': {0: array([[ 35.74  , -95.36],
         [ 36.19 , -95.92]]),
  1: array([[ 35.82, -95.67],
         [ 35.98 , -95.81 ]]),
  2: array([[ 36.27, -95.91],
         [ 36.08 , -95.96 ]]),
  3: array([[ 35.99 , -95.88],
         [ 35.75 , -95.34]]),
  4: array([[ 36.18, -96.40],
         [ 36.07 , -95.89 ]])}}
```

Comment: `df[['TeamA']].join(pd.DataFrame(df.TeamB.values.tolist()))`

Comment: ValueError: Must pass 2-d input. The data-frame inside join wont work.

Comment: updated, but it's the same format

Comment: Post the output of `df.head(5).to_dict()`

Comment: updated in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the sol. we can use `from_records`

```
    pd.DataFrame.from_records(df['TeamB'])
```